# A necessary condition for a property of sub-gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is Exercise 2.5.4 in [High Dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) by Vershynin.

The question is:

Show that $\mathbb{E} X=0$ is a necessary condition for $$ \mathbb{E} \exp\left( \lambda X \right) \leq \exp \left(K^2\lambda^2 \right) \text{ for all } \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$$
I have tried to prove in the following ways, but in both cases I cant get the desired result.

(i) $\mathbb{E} \exp\left( \lambda X \right) \leq \exp \left(K^2\lambda^2 \right) \text{ for all } \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}X=0$

(ii) $\mathbb{E}X \neq 0 \Rightarrow \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t }\mathbb{E} \exp\left( \lambda X \right) > \exp \left(K^2\lambda^2 \right) $

In both situations, I tried to use Taylor expansion and some inequalities to bound the MGF, but it seems that it has nothing to do with the first moment.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a direct proof.

Using Jensen's Inqequality, we have $$ \exp \left( \lambda \mathbb{E} X\right) \leq \mathbb{E}\exp \left( \lambda X\right)\leq \exp \left(K^2 \lambda ^2  \right) \text{ for all } \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \\ 
\Rightarrow  K^2 \lambda^2 - \lambda \mathbb{E} X \geq 0\\ $$

Note that it's quadratic in $\lambda$, consider the discriminant, we have
$\left( \mathbb{E}X \right)^2 \leq 0.$

Therefore, $\mathbb{E}X=0$